# A word meaning random but restricted

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single english word that means an object will take on a random / unpredictable attribute, but restricted to a known set of values?

For example, in programming, generating a random number but it is between 0 and 10

I feel like it is heavily related to probability, but I'm looking for a word that does not imply equal probability or known probabilities for each attribute.

Another example would be a light that can be red, blue, or green. each time you look at it you will see a "random" color, but it is restricted within a set of colors.

Example usage: But it was no ordinary die, you didn't roll it; because it was ____, simply observing it gave a random result.

Comment: I don't think there is a single word. How about "random but bounded".  P.S. Your example sounds rather like a description of quantum theory! The observation causes the result! (or rather a collapse of the probability waveform)

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica (Im not actually writing anything, I have a degree in physics and saw a single word request on popular questions and thought it would be fun to ask a question like this)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *aleatory*

> in British English
>
> 1. dependent on chance
> 2. (esp of a musical composition) involving elements chosen at random by the performer
>
> Collins English dictionary
>
> Word origin
> C17: from Latin āleātōrius, from āleātor gambler, from ālea game of chance, dice, of uncertain origin suggest *aleatory*

Although the main meaning is similar to *random* the etymology of the word relates to chance selection from a limited number of possibilities (such as in dice, or cards) rather than selection from an unbounded set, and therefore suits your purpose.

Comment: 'Aleatory' carries no connotation of 'restricted to a limited number of possibilities' in most dictionaries I've checked in and the faintest hint from Lexico. And certainly no flavour of 'a word that does not imply equal probability or known probabilities for each attribute'. Ballpark answers, gross hypernyms, aren't scholarly.

Comment: Oh really! The etymology comes from the gambling table, where the possibilities are necessarily limited. The overtones are right there in the etymology and are to be found in the neat Latinism *Alea jacta est*, “the die is cast”.  The same goes for aleatory music, which is necessarily confined to the limited (although large) number of notes available to the composer. My hints are not faint, and in any case the lack of faint hints would not, as any logical mathematician will know, be proof of the non-existence of faint hints.

Comment: 'Uncertainties are characterized as epistemic, if the modeler sees a possibility to reduce them by gathering more data or by refining models. Uncertainties are categorized as aleatory if the modeler does not foresee the possibility of reducing them.' [[ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167473008000556) seems a precising definition that throws connotations on other usages which are the reverse of the etymologically posited ones you say. I see that you fail to provide recent examples of the usage (demanding / strongly suggesting ...

Comment: a limited set of possibilities, inherently rather than from context) and to mention with what frequency 'aleatory' is used in this way. The U in ELU stands for _standard_ usage.

Comment: Well, there we are. I suspect that few people are interested in our trivial spat.

Comment: If OP or another visitor loses a critical mark in an essay because an examiner considers 'aleatory' at best pretentious, I'd not consider my comments trivial.